# Return Type Best Practice - Page<Employee> vs Set<Employee>

Tags: java

I saw in web application project where the return type or response type to the service APIs have the following signatures

either with Page or With List of Set

`Page<Employee>` vs `Set<Employee>` vs `List<Employee>`

Not sure when we go to return as a Page<> and when to return as Set or List

Comment: How can we advise when we don't know the `Page` class?

Comment: check page properties, hash properties and list properties you will get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of how much you know about collections in Java. I will be brief to eliminate confusion.

**Page**

*It is a sublist of a list of objects.* One may implement *page* for enforcing pagination.

For instance, say you have records in the database and you do not want to get all of the data at once. Probably, maybe, you would love to get the first 5 records, then the second 5 from the record and so on. *This is why they define Page as a sublist of a list.*

**Set**

*A list/collection that contains no duplicate elements/values.* For instance one may return a set to get rid of duplicates in a list/collection.

**List**

*A list is an ordered collection (also known as a sequence).* Sets (as explained above) do not allow duplicates, but List do.

I hope this finds you well :)

Answer (score 0):

Absent any information about what `Page` is, there is quite a big difference in the connotations of the name:

- `Set` is an maybe-unordered bag of things, without duplicates; it perhaps implies that it is all of the "things".
- `Page` is just part of the collection of all "things". It implies the collection is ordered, in order that you can say "this is page N, now I want page N+1".

These properties are not intended to be exhaustive, and they may not be correct; this is merely what I would expect from an API using one or the other.

Assuming this is `java.util.Set`, returning a `Set` allows the return value to be used in "standard" ways, e.g. checking if an element is present, iterating it with an enhanced for loop, copying into some other list/set. `Page` may also allow doing these things, but that depends on how it is declared; but `Page` may also have useful methods that are not found on the `Set` interface.

The appropriate choice is the one appropriate to your problem.

Comment: isn't `Page` is only applicable for Java Spring

Comment: @Jacky `Page` could be any class. There is nothing to indicate this is a question about Spring.